# How can I set query string in fetchAPI

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

Is this the best way to set querystring in using fetchAPI?

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('id', 2);
params.set('word', 'hello');
fetch('https://example.com/?' + params.toString())
```

I don't think this is the best way because instantiation of URLSearchParams , append the '?' to the end of domain name and using toString method is dull.
If I can I want to write as below.

```
fetch('https://example.com/').params([id:2, word: 'hello']);
```

Comment: seeing as fetch returns a promise, what you propose is ridiculous

Comment: @JaromandaX My example is wrong exactly. I want to say `fetch(url, {
params:[id:2, word: 'hello']}`. But your pointing out is helpful for me.

Comment: @Andreas I think I will be able to write my fetching code more readably with your recommended other question. Thank you.